# Changing an array value java

Tags: java, arrays, list, indexing

So I have set up an array 'generateUser' in a method called by my main. However, when i run it, it replaces the value the index with a cumulative i value. instead of every time the dectile 7, for example, comes up it just replaces index 7 with the current value of i. i see what is wrong, but I don't know how to fix it. I think the problem line is

list[k]=++i;//HELP

```
public static int [] generateUser(int n)
{
    //pass number of students int n;
    int [] list = new int[10];
   int i=0;
    int total, counter, k;
    int score;
    String str3;
    total = counter =0;


   while (total < n)
   {

    str3 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the score: (1-100) ");
    score = Integer.parseInt(str3);
    System.out.print(str3+"\t");
        if (score <1 || score >100)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"The data must be betwen 1 and      100.");
            }
      k = (score-1)/10;

      list[k]=++i;//HELP
      total = counter ++;
    }
      return list;
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand where you're setting `i`. Don't you simply want:

```
 list[k]++;
```

to incremement the decile found at index `k` ?

Comment: I had it has list[k]=++; I cannot believe I just spent an hour trying to fix that. Thanks Brian!

Answer (score 0):

I thing you want something like that:

```
list[counter]=k;
```

because u want a to fill a list with **10** users at the end?

with `list[k]=++i;` you don't set your index. You set the Value at position **k** in the array list.